# Two tables with the same number

Tags: tables, numbering

Suppose I have three tables on three separate pages. If the first table is captioned **Table 1: Basic Estimations**, I want the second table to be captioned **Table 1: Basic Estimations (continued)** and the third (logical) table to be captioned **Table 2: Further Estimations**.

How do I achieve this? Just for an example, I used the following command to manually change the second table's caption. But it led to the third table being captioned as **Table 3: Further Estimations**.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand\thetable{1}
\caption{Basic Estimations (continued)}
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\ hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may achieve your typesetting objective by loading the `caption` package and by insering a `\ContinuedFloat` directive immediately after the second `\begin{table}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption} % for '\ContinuedFloat' directive
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering\caption{Basic Estimations}
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\ContinuedFloat  %% <-- new
\centering\caption{Basic Estimations (continued)}
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering\caption{Further Estimations}
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum to address the OP's follow-up query*: A side-benefit of employing the `\ContinuedFloat` approach is that it's possible to create separate cross-references to the initial and to the continued part of a LaTeX `table` or `figure`. (As always, be sure to issue the `\label` instructions *after* the `\caption` instructions.) Let's assume that "Table 1" comes in two separate parts. If the labels are `\label{tab:1}` and `\label{tab:1-cont}`, one can create separate cross-referencing call-outs via `\ref{tab:1}` and `\ref{tab:1-cont}`. Both call-outs will be numbered "1"; to avoid any confusion among your readers, be sure to write something like `In the initial part of Table \ref{tab:1}` and `in the continued part of Table \ref{tab:1}`.

The following MWE (minimum working example) employs the `hyperref` and `cleveref`  packages to make it easier to identify the LaTeX-generated cross-referencing call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption} % for '\ContinuedFloat' directive
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref} 
\begin{document}
\noindent
Cross-references to the first part of \cref{tab:1}, to the continued 
part of \cref{tab:1-cont}, and to \cref{tab:2}.

\clearpage
\begin{table}
\centering\caption{Basic Estimations} \label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\begin{table}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering\caption{Basic Estimations (continued)} \label{tab:1-cont}
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\begin{table}
\centering\caption{Further Estimations} \label{tab:2}
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A separate advantage of the `\ContinuedFloat` approach is that it's possible to create separate cross-references (via the usual `\label`-`\ref` method) to both the initial and the continued parts of the table of interest.

Comment: Perfect. Just as I wanted. Am I allowed to thank here? By the way, I was going to ask it, but you already hinted at it. Can I use `\label` under `\ContinuedFloat` just in the usual way we do it for ordinary tables?

Comment: @TRa - You're most welcome. I've posted an addendum to address your follow-up question in greater detail.